# Object can be used as class name even though a predefined Object class exists

Tags: object, java

i have created a class X in com.x package, since X class is there it didn't allowed me to create a class with name 'X' again.
now, i created a package java.lang and created a Object class with main method

its created, how it is allowing to create a class with same name and same package which is already exists.

when i try to execute it has thrown the below error

Error: Main method not found in class java.lang.Object, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

why is it happening? i know its pointing to predefined Object class and it didn't find main method.
thanks.

Comment: can some one clarify me? if you are not able to understand the question pls reply the same.